# Android App only reading last extra message from intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to pass three messages from one activity to another. However Android Studio is only looking at the last created "putExtra" and applying it to all outputs. My code is below.

First activity where intent is created:

```
     public void buttonOnClick_Goals(View v) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Goals.class);

    EditText benchpress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtBenchpress);
    String benchpress_message = benchpress.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(BENCH_PR, benchpress_message);

    EditText squat = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtSquat);
    String squat_message = squat.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(SQUAT_PR, squat_message);

    EditText deadlift = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtDeadlift);
    String deadlift_message = deadlift.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(DEAD_PR, deadlift_message);

    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Second activity where text fields are set to the passed messages:

```
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_goals);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String bench_message = intent.getStringExtra(PersonalRecords.BENCH_PR);
    String squat_message = intent.getStringExtra(PersonalRecords.SQUAT_PR);
    String dead_message = intent.getStringExtra(PersonalRecords.DEAD_PR);

    TextView benchText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtbenchpr);
    benchText.setText(bench_message, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);

    TextView squatText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtsquatpr);
    squatText.setText(squat_message, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);

    TextView deadText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtdeadpr);
    deadText.setText(dead_message, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);

}
```

Comment: The only thing need to check are values of `PersonalRecords.BENCH_PR`,`PersonalRecords.SQUAT_PR` and `PersonalRecords.DEAD_PR` .

Comment: Most likely your 3 extra keys have the same value, in which case they are the same extra, and only the last value you put is actually sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure BENCH_PR, SQUAT_PR and DEAD_PR have different values!